# How do I create a variable for my terraform CSV file?

Tags: terraform

I have a CSV file that I'm using to create a local variable in my main.tf file using the csvdecode function. I'm then using a GitHub module to deploy resources and need to create the variable github_organization in variable.tf within this module. I have the variable created for a JSON file, but I am unsure of how to create it for the CSV. Here's an example of the CSV file:

```
default_repository_permission,name,email,members_username,members_role
read,Terraform,noreply@abc.com,S11111,member
,,,S22222,admin
,,,S33333,member
```

How can I create the variable for this CSV file in my terraform-github-module-labs.git module? Here's the variable I already have for the JSON file:

```
variable "github_organization" {
 type = object({
 name                                                     = string
 email                                                    = string
 description                                              = optional(string, "")
 default_repository_permission                            = optional(string, "read")
 members_can_fork_private_repositories                    = optional(bool, false)
 dependabot_alerts_enabled_for_new_repositories           = optional(bool, true)
 dependabot_security_updates_enabled_for_new_repositories = optional(bool, true)
 dependency_graph_enabled_for_new_repositories            = optional(bool, true)
 members = optional(list(object({
  username = string
  role     = string
 })), [])
})
}
```